# Ploneboard conflict with AccessControl?

Tags: plone, zope

i’m trying to install the latest Ploneboard (v3.6) on a Plone 4.2 site, but getting the error

`The version, 2.13.11, is not consistent with the requirement, AccessControl>=3.0`

i see that [the most recent Ploneboard change log](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Ploneboard#id1) for this version mentions "Fixed dependency for AccessControl. Plone < 4.3 have an old version pinned [cekk]”

anyone see what is wrong in this picture?  thanks for any clues.

Comment: i guess i should also say that while i understand what 'pinning' versions means, i don't find any specification of any contraints on AccessControl any where in `buildout.cfg`, `versions.cfg`, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 3.6 PloneBoard requires `AccessControl>=3.0`.

The Problem in your case is, that Plone 4.2.x has an older version pinned:
Check: http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2-latest/

If you run `./bin/buildout annotate | grep -C 5 AccessControl`. 
You will see which buildout configuration pins the version of AccessControl.

```
...
[versions]
AccessControl= 2.13.13
    http://dist.plone.org/release/4.2-latest/versions.cfg
...
```

In your case you need to override this version pinning in your buildout.cfg (or versions.cfg).

```
[versions]
AccessControl = 3.0.8  # For example
```

I don't know which version of AccessControl works with Plone 4.2.x.
But 3.0.x seems suitable.

Comment: I can confirm, we are using AccessControl 3.0.8 in production on a Plone 4.2.4 site due to PloneBoard recent requirements.

Comment: @keul Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: pinning AccessControl = 3.0.8 works, thanks Mathias!  (and also thanks for the `annotate` argument to buildout; teach a person to fish...)   any clue why the Ploneboard changelog mentions this as fixed in v3.6?

Comment: No, probably they had security issues with AccessControl 2.13.x. Ask the contributor iteself (cekk - you can find him on github).